# Typescript: How to say a variable is of type moment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have an interface which has a callback and it takes two parameters which are moment object. Here is how it looks like

```
interface IProps {
  callback: (startDate: any, endDate: any) => void
}
```

This is working for me but I want to be more specific and say that they are not any but moment like so which results in an error:

```
interface IProps {
  callback: (startDate: moment, endDate: moment) => void
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the moment interface supposed to be? where is it defined?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [moment.d.ts](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.d.ts)

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

interface IProps {
  callback: (startDate: moment.Moment, endDate: moment.Moment) => void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the `moment` interface/class to your file with:
`import { moment } from "moment";`